# Control flow graph & cyclomatic complexity for following procedure

Tags: c, control-flow, cyclomatic-complexity, black-box, white-box

```
insertion_procedure (int a[], int p [], int N)
{
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0; i<=N; i++) p[i] = i;
    for (i=2; i<=N; i++)
    {
        k = p[i];
        j = 1;
        while (a[p[j-1]] > a[k]) {p[j] = p[j-1]; j--}
        p[j] = k;
    }
}
```

I have to find cyclomatic complexity for this code and then suggest some white box test cases and black box test cases. But I am having trouble making a CFG for the code.

Would appreciate some help on test cases as well.

Comment: What language is this?  It looks like C except for the "Int" rather than "int" in the declaration.  If it is C, there is no nested for loop, but ratehr a while loop nested in a for loop.

Comment: Oh yes there is no nested for loop. Its C

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Start by numbering the statements:

```
 insertion_procedure (int a[], int p [], int N)
 {
(1)    Int i,j,k;
(2)    for ((2a)i=0; (2b)i<=N; (2c)i++) 
(3)        p[i] = i;
(4)    for ((4a)i=2; (4b)i<=N; (4c)i++)
       {
(5)       k=p[i];j=1;
(6)       while (a[p[j-1]] > a[k]) {
(7)           p[j] = p[j-1]; 
(8)           j--
          }
(9)          p[j] = k;
       }
```

Now you can clearly see which statement executes first and which last etc. so drawing the cfg becomes simple.

[image: CFG]

Now, to calculate cyclomatic complexity you use one of three methods:

1. Count the number of regions on the graph: 4
2. No. of predicates (red on graph) + 1 : 3 + 1 = 4
3. No of edges - no. of nodes + 2: 14 - 12 + 2 = 4.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what tool did you use to generate the flow graph?

Comment: @James McNellis I used MS Visio to draw the CFG.

Comment: Ah; I thought it might have been created by some sort of code analysis tool.  +1 for taking the effort to draw a really good picture!

Comment: totally appreciate the effort. Thanks!

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie Nice explanation. However, I have one doubt: isn't it possible that the control from 4b could directly jump to the end of the function? (similar to a jump from 2b to 4a)? Is there a specific reason the same is not considered? What am I missing here?

Comment: Actually @Jay you may be right. 4B is a predicate and as such should have 2 arrows leaving. Strange how no one picked up on that before.

Comment: Ok.. I got it. It will go from 4b to 10 but not from 9 to 10. So total regions will remain the same.

Answer (score 3):

The cyclomatic complexity is 4.

1 for the procedure +1 for the for loop +1 for the while loop +1 for the if condition of the while loop.

Comment: Yes but they are at the same level of nesting, so there's a single path through the code, no ifs.

Comment: @AJ. totally agree with you. Have added a similar comment just now in the original answer. Or else, if you know the explanation, you can add it here for benefit of all.

Comment: 2 For  + 1 while + 1 procedure = 4 .

Need a help if can you confirm the veracity of this wiki Link here.
I think the complexity would be 4 here. but it is mentioned 3. I need someone to testify me.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity#/media/File:Control_flow_graph_of_function_with_loop_and_an_if_statement.svg

Answer (score 2):

You can also use McCabe formula `M = E-N + 2C` 
    E = edges
    N = nodes
    C = components
    M = cyclomatic complexity

```
E = 14
N = 12
C = 1
```

`M = 14-12 + 2*1 = 4`